# MatLab: Find numeric values in cell array

Tags: matlab, find, cell-array

In my cell array `test = cell(1,2,20,14);` I want to find numeric values in the subset test(:,1,1,1).

For example `test(:,:,1,1)` looks like this:

```
>> test(:,:,1,1)

ans = 

[     0]    [0.1000]    [57]
[0.9000]    [0.9500]    [73]
```

I want to find the index of the cell containing 0.9 in the first column, so I can access the third column (in this case value 73). I tried:

`find(test{:,:,1,1} == 0.9)` which gives:

`Error using  == Too many input arguments.`.

How can I find the respective index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to access that third column value directly -

```
cell2mat(test(vertcat(test{:,1,1,1})==0.9,3,1,1))
```

**Edit 1:** If you would like to test out for match w.r.t. the first two columns of `test`'s subset, use this -

```
v1 = reshape(vertcat(test{:,[1 2],1,1}),[],2)
cell2mat(test(ismember(v1,[0.9 0.95],'rows'),3,1,1))
```

Comment: Really nice! Could you also extend this code to two conditions like: Give me third column where first column == 0.9 and second column is 0.95?

Comment: @PeterRussel Check out **Edit 1** !

Answer (score 1):

Just add brackets `[]` around `test{:,:,1,1}`. This wraps the different cell values together to one vector/matrix.
Like this:

```
[index1, index2] = find([test{:,:,1,1}] == 0.9)
```